# Python regex match text between quotes

Tags: python, regex

In the following script I would like to pull out text between the double quotes ("). However, the python interpreter is not happy and I can't figure out why...

```
import re

text = 'Hello, "find.me-_/\\" please help with python regex'
pattern = r'"([A-Za-z0-9_\./\\-]*)"'
m = re.match(pattern, text)

print m.group()
```

The output should be `find.me-/\`.

Comment: btw, you can simplify the pattern:
 pattern = r'"([^"]*)"'

Comment: `re.findall(pattern, text)` can also be helpful if you need to match all of the the quotes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) starts searching from the beginning of the text.

Use [`search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

text = 'Hello, "find.me-_/\\" please help with python regex'
pattern = r'"([A-Za-z0-9_\./\\-]*)"'
m = re.search(pattern, text)

print m.group()
```

`match` and `search` return `None` when they fail to match.

I guess you are getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` from python: This is because you are assuming you will match without checking the return from `re.match`.

Comment: How can I check if they returned null or not?

Comment: `if m is None`: doStuffIfNoMatch() else: doStuffIfMatch()`

Answer (score 4):

If you write:

```
m = re.search(pattern, text)
```

**match**: searches at the beginning of text

**search**: searches all the string

Maybe this helps you to understand:
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching

Answer (score 4):

Split the text on quotes and take every other element starting with the second element:

```
def text_between_quotes(text):
    return text.split('"')[1::2]

my_string = 'Hello, "find.me-_/\\" please help and "this quote" here'
my_string.split('"')[1::2]           # ['find.me-_/\\', 'this quote']
'"just one quote"'.split('"')[1::2]  # ['just one quote']
```

This assumes you don't have quotes within quotes, and your text doesn't mix quotes or use [other quoting characters](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/quotes.html) like `` ` ``.

You should validate your input. For example, what do you want to do if there's an odd number of quotes, meaning not all the quotes are balanced? You could do something like discard the last item if you have an even number of things after doing the `split`

```
def text_between_quotes(text):
    split_text = text.split('"')
    between_quotes = split_text[1::2]
    # discard the last element if the quotes are unbalanced
    if len(split_text) % 2 == 0 and between_quotes and not text.endswith('"'):
        between_quotes.pop()
    return between_quotes

# ['first quote', 'second quote']
text_between_quotes('"first quote" and "second quote" and "unclosed quote')
```

or raise an error instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match) instead of `re.match()`. The latter will match only *at the beginning* of strings (like an implicit `^`).

Answer (score 1):

You need `re.search()`, not `re.match()` which is anchored to the start of your input string.

Docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching)