# How to check if a line contains a string in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if a subString exists in a string using regular expression.

RE : `re_string_literal = '^"[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+"$'`

The thing is, I don't want to match any substring. I'm reading data from a file:

Now one of the lines have this text:
`cout<<"Hello"<<endl;`

I just want to check if there's a string inside the line and if yes, store it in a list.

I have tried the re.match method but it only works if we have to match a pattern, but in this case, I just want to check if a string exists or not, if yes, store it somewhere.

```
re_string_lit = '^"[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+"$'

text = 'cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl;'

re.match(re_string_lit,text)
```

It doesn't output anything.

In simple words,
I just want to extract everything inside ""

Comment: `re.match` works just fine for this, but you have not shown any code. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean if a string exists or not? ***It is*** a string... To check if it's not empty you can do `if s.strip():`

Comment: You have prematurely added the `^` and `$` markers to your regular expression. Remove them, and `re.match` takes care of finding the desired string anywhere inside the input string.

Comment: @chepner not accurate. `re.match` only matches from the ***start*** of the string. `re.search` will look everywhere...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks. I always get the two mixed up.

Comment: One of your examples has a `!` in the input string, which is not part of your regular expression. You might want to use `[^"]` rather than trying to enumerate all allowed characters, but then you need to address the issue of a string like `"foo\"bar"`.

Comment: Are you always looking for strings inside `cout<<**<<endl`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo No, it can be anywhere.

Comment: It looks like you're parsing a C++ file. So you basically want to check if there is an actual string in the code line? Why not just `'"' in line`? As far as I can tell, that must mean a string...

Comment: @Tomerikoo You are right.

Comment: @QasimKhan What about quotes inside comments? Do you want actual C++ strings, or just anything that's surrounded by quotes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regex match text between quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085558/python-regex-match-text-between-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract everything inside "" then string splitting would be much simpler way of doing things.

```
>>> a = 'something<<"actualString">>something,else'
>>> b = a.split('"')[1]
>>> b
'actualString'
```

The above example would only work for not more than 2 instances of double quotes ("), but you could make it work by iterating over every substring extracted using split method and applying a much simpler Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
re.search('"(.+?)"', 'cout<<"Hello"<<endl')
```

Comment: `"([^"]+)"` is a bit more efficient than a lazy quantifier on `.`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thankyou so much. Is there a way to access this substring after performing the search method?

Comment: Yes. it is stored in group 1. So, `match = re.search('"(.+?)"', 'cout<<"Hello"<<endl')` and the string is `match.group(1)`. If you want it ***with*** the quotes, then it's `group(0)` or just `group()`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you so much!